# Again, 'return' outside function

Tags: python, return

I'm trying to write a module that calculates the least common multiple, but I always get the same error: **'return' outside function**

```
def lcm(x,y):

amin = min(x,y)

for j in range(1, amin + 1) :

     if(x%j==0 and y%j==0) :

          jmax = j

          z= (x*y)/(jmax)

     return z
```

I tried to indent the `return` line, but it's actually indented at the same level as the `if`, I don't know what to do.

Comment: You need to indent from the `def`

Comment: @Fejs I reverted your edit, given that wrong indentation was the very error being discussed in this question.

Answer (score 1):

The function body also needs to be indented:

```
def lcm(x,y):
    amin = min(x,y)

    for j in range(1, amin + 1) :
         if x%j==0 and y%j==0 :  # also, no need to use parentheses there
              jmax = j
              z= (x*y)/(jmax)

    return z
```

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glace: you have defined a function with `def` but put no code in it. The `amin` and your for loop are both indented the same as the `def`. Try indenting them by 4 spaces to make them part of your function.

So

```
def your_function():
    amin = something
    for i in x:
        # do something
    return xyz
```

Comment: Indent them by 4 spaces like pep8 specifies ;)

Comment: I indented by 4 but said two. My apologies